# Limiting top score results returned based on conditional (same value of a field) ElasticSearch Aggregations

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, search-engine

Is there a way to pull up only the top 2 results based on _score for docs with the same value in a certain field?

the hits before this filter or aggretation would be like:

```
{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":100,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i have a twin",
      "name":"fred"
    }
},

{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":50,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i have a twin",
      "name":"george"
    }
},

{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":10,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i have a twin",
      "name":"tom"
    }
},

{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":10,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i DONT have a twin",
      "name":"doug"
    }
}
```

Then after this filter/agg I want this ... tom removed because he has same value for myfield1, but the lowest score. Doug stays because he has a different value for myfield1.

```
{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":100,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i have a twin",
      "name":"fred"
    }
},

{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":50,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i have a twin",
      "name":"george"
    }
},

{ 
   "_index":"myindex",
   "_score":10,
   "_source": {
      "myfield1": "i DONT have a twin",
      "name":"doug"
    }
}
```

I was hoping this would have the right effect ... but it didn't. Am I close?

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                "myfield1": {
                  "query": "i have",
                  "fuzziness": 1,
                  "slop": 2,
                  "max_expansions": 10,
                  "prefix_length": 1
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * [...] "
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myfield1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myfield1",
        "size": 2,
        "order": {
          "max_score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "field": "_doc.score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To secure that you only get 2 answers for a given query, make sure to include the parameter "size" : 2 outside of the aggs (on the same level as query and aggs in your example). The size parameter tells ES how many answers you want (i.e. how many search results you request), which for your first part should be 2. So

"query" : {...},

...other stuff... ,

"size" : 2

should get you 2 hits, for the given query (your first hits).

Also, I am not sure, but it looks like your basically want to search for the documents and return the documents (your wanted example result indicates this). If that is the case you dont need the aggregations, only the search results.

So basically you could try just sending two separate search requests using the multi_search endpoint (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Hope that helps.